# Mongo Db Aggregation with $project and $max

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below is my sample document: I want to get the errors for the max version using aggregation query.

```
{
    "_id": {
      "objectIdentifier": {
        "identifier": {
          "Empid": "715e66c7-92ff-4619-9324-2c708489fe27"
        },
        "objectName": "EmployeeInfoValidationValue"
      },
      "Empid": "715e66c7-92ff-4619-9324-2c708489fe27"
    },
    "Versions": [
      {
        "errors": [
          {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "message": "Employee Name missing",
            "timestamp": NumberLong(1531509214154)
          }
        ],
        "resultSetId": "6314a9b1-1bb0-4ba7-8128-9db39085339c",
        "scope": "INPUT_QUALITY",
        "validationLevelSeverity": "ERROR",
        "validationResultsIdentifier": {
          "identifier": {
            "objectIdentifier": {
              "identifier": {
                "Empid": "715e66c7-92ff-4619-9324-2c708489fe27"
              },
              "objectName": "EmployeeInfoValidationValue"
            },
            "Empid": "715e66c7-92ff-4619-9324-2c708489fe27"
          },
          "objectName": "ValidationResult"
        },
        "version": NumberLong(10039)
      },
      {
        "errors": [
          {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "message": "Employee Name length is not within specified range",
            "timestamp": NumberLong(1531123789457)
          }
        ],
        "resultSetId": "8743100a-1464-46af-b4d6-6636c47c8f36",
        "scope": "INPUT_QUALITY",
        "validationLevelSeverity": null,
        "validationResultsIdentifier": {
          "identifier": {
            "objectIdentifier": {
              "identifier": {
                "Empid": "715e66c7-92ff-4619-9324-2c708489fe27"
              },
              "objectName": "EmployeeInfoValidationValue"
            },
            "Empid": "715e66c7-92ff-4619-9324-2c708489fe27"
          },
          "objectName": "ValidationResult"
        },
        "version": NumberLong(10097)
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have written the aggregation query and it shows up all records that has max version - For example shows max version :  `NumberLong(10097)`. I am not sure how to display the `Versions.errors` as "Employee Name length is not within specified range" in this case. 
This is the query I wrote:

```
db.ValidationResults.aggregate(
    [
            {
            $match: { 
                "_id.Empid" : "715e66c7-92ff-4619-9324-2c708489fe27",
                "Versions.scope" : "INPUT_QUALITY"
            }
        },

        {
          $project:
            {
                versionMax: {$max: "$Versions.version"}
     }
 }
 ]
     )
```

I tried `$addFields` to show the errors but it only returns null(not working). TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your `versionMax` in the next pipeline stage with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get single-item array where `version` is equal to `$max` value. Then you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to transform one-element array into an object:

```
db.ValidationResults.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            Versions: 1,
            MaxVersion: { $max: "$Versions.version" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            Versions: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Versions",
                    as: "x",
                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$x.version", "$MaxVersion" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$Versions"
    }
])
```